# Error mergetool code compare in git

Tags: git, mergetool, codecompare

when I do git pull I've got some conflicts but I trying fix this conflicts with mergetool (code compare) I get this error:

[image: Error mergetool code compare]

my configuration of .gitconfig is this:

```
[core]
    autocrlf=false
[difftool "codecompare"]
cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codecompare.exe' -W \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" 
renames = true

[diff]
tool = codecompare
guitool = codecompare

[mergetool "codecompare"]
cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codemerge.exe' -MF=\"$LOCAL\" -TF=\"$REMOTE\" -BF=\"$BASE\" -RF=\"$MERGED\" 
trustExitCode = true

[mergetool]
keepBackup = false

[merge]
tool = codecompare
guitool = codecompare
```

the arguments are populating like:

ARGUMENTS:

```
"-MF=./DBchanges/file change DB1.0_LOCAL_3972.sql" 
"-TF=./DBchanges/file change DB1.0_REMOTE_3972.sql" 
"-BF=./DBchanges/file change DB1.0_BASE_3972.sql" 
"-RF=DBchanges/file change DB1.0.sql"
```

Do anybody know what could be the reason?

thanks everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

the problem is in this line:

```
[mergetool "codecompare"]
cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codemerge.exe' -MF=\"$LOCAL\" -TF=\"$REMOTE\" -BF=\"$BASE\" -RF=\"$MERGED\"
```

we need change the simbols '=' for a space (`-MF \"$LOCAL\"`) because the arguments are quoted like:

```
"-MF=./DBchanges/file change DB1.0_LOCAL_3972.sql"
```

and has to be like:

```
-MF "./DBchanges/file change DB1.0_LOCAL_3972.sql"
```